# How to know if a child exists on any nest level in a tree structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a tree table, as showing:

```
TREE (TreeID int PK, ParentID int)
```

What I'm trying to figure is if I select a Tree item, how to know if the child exists in any sub level of its parent, and if it was a function, I would assume it would look something like this?

```
@ParentID --@param, The TreeID of the Tree item in focus

SELECT TreeID 
FROM TREE 
WHERE dbo.IsATreeChild(TreeID,@ParentID) = 1
```

Basically, If `TreeId` `IsATreeChild` of `@ParentID` it should return true. I just can't understand how to do this either way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you're after recursive queries using CTEs as defined in the linked example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Right, but I still don't know how to check if something exists on any sub levels. Or only return below a certain level/sub-level.

Comment: ok a better response then is to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956929/find-all-the-leaf-nodes-below-a-subtree-in-a-tree-structure-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive CTEs are quite common helpers for trees handling.

Probably you may find useful following functions:

```
create function dbo.ftTreeNodeChildren(@treeID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    with Children(TreeID) as (
        select TreeID
        from Tree
        where ParentID = @treeID
        union all
        select T.TreeID
        from Children C
            join Tree T on T.ParentID = C.TreeID
    )
    select TreeID
    from Children
GO
```

It can be used then as:

```
select TreeID
from dbo.ftTreeNodeChildren(@treeID)
```

which should list children of `@treeID` (if there are any).

Sometimes it can be useful to include `@treeID` itself. In this case similar function can be used:

```
create function dbo.ftTreeNodeSubtree(@treeID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    with Subtree(TreeID) as (
        select TreeID
        from Tree
        where TreeID = @treeID
        union all
        select T.TreeID
        from Subtree S
            join Tree T on T.ParentID = S.TreeID
    )
    select TreeID
    from Subtree
GO
```

which should list children or `@treeID` (if there are any) including `@treeID` itself.

upd.: To check that `@treeID` is a child of `@parentID` at any level you can use first function as:

```
if exists (
    select 1
    from dbo.ftTreeNodeChildren(@parentID)
    where TreeID = @treeID
)
    print '@treeID is a child of @parentID'
else
    print '@treeID is NOT a child of @parentID'
```

Comment: Using a CTE for this gives horrible performance. I did it using a WHILE statement and got it to go significantly quicker. But you had the best answer, Thank you.

Comment: @ZeeTee, not sure it outperform `WHILE`, but (assuming `TreeID` is PK clustered), you may try `create index IX_Tree_ParentID on Tree (ParentID)` also, which should help walking the tree.

Comment: As a function that returns 1 value, the while version works 10x quicker. Here is an example:
`WHILE @@rowcount > 0 BEGIN SET @Val = @pathName + ' > ' + @Val; SELECT @pathID = ParentID, @pathName = TREEName From dbo.TREE  where ID = @pathID; END`